# how to use uniVocity-parsers to process non-printable character

Tags: java, non-printing-characters, univocity

I would like to use Java with **uniVocity-parsers** to parse the csv data which is produced by mysql `select into outfile`.

**Now I encounter one situation of processing non-printable characters !** The mysql table contains `bit(1)` column and when using `select into outfile` to save it's data into file, I found that the `bit(1)` column data become non-printable character. When using **uniVocity-parsers** to get line data, I get `null` value of the `bit(1)` columns. I expect to get real data of the `bit(1)` column. What should I do ?

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of the CSV you are trying to parse so I can have a look?

Comment: [csv data with non-printable characters](http://od0hvfbed.bkt.clouddn.com/data/txt/tab_web_user-unhex-data.txt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the `bit(1)` values are being exported by MySQL as characters `\u0000` and `\u0001`, and the parser by default trims all values (meaning any character `<= ' '`). The trimming process will wipe out the `\u0000` and `\u0001` as their integer representations are `0` and `1` respectively, while the integer representation of a whitespace character `' '` is `32`.

You just need to configure that parser to prevent trimming the values:

```
    settings.trimValues(false);
```

Also, the file you gave has lines terminated with `\r\n`. If you parse this on OSX or Linux you need to define the line endings explicitly:

```
    settings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\r\n");
```

Or enable auto-detection with:

```
    settings.setLineSeparatorDetectionEnabled(true);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, you are right ! I have debugged into the source code and find the answer why non-printable characters will be ignored ! Thank you very much!